# Getting error on using WCF Service with CSLA

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, csla

I have a create a Wcf Service using WcfPortal.It exposes basic method Fetch,Delete,Insert and Update. I use this Service in my MVC project as below

```
 ServiceReference2.WcfPortalClient obj = new ServiceReference2.WcfPortalClient();
 Application App = new Application();
 var AppType = App.GetType();
 ApplicationCriteria Criteria = new ApplicationCriteria {ApplicationName = "application" };
 ServiceReference2.FetchRequest Fetch1 = new ServiceReference2.FetchRequest();
 CslaTest.ServiceReference2.DataPortalContext context = new ServiceReference2.DataPortalContext();
 Fetch1._context = context;
 Fetch1._objectType= AppType;
 Fetch1._criteria = Criteria;
 var list = obj.Fetch(Fetch1);
```

But when i compile my project i get error as:

> Type 'CslaTest.BusinessLibrary.ApplicationCriteria' with data contract name 
>   ApplicationCriteria:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/CslaTest.BusinessLibrary' is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver or add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.'

Comment: Why are you directly using a WCF Client and not the Client DataPortal?